# compact statement to fill vector with restricted permutation of values while keeping existing in R

Tags: r

I'm having a target vector

```
> x <- c(rep(NA, 5), "b", rep(NA, 2))
> x
[1] NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  "b" NA  NA
```

and values, e.g.,

```
> vals <- letters[1:3]
```

I'm looking for general a way to fill the missing values in `x` with cyclic occurrences of the values in `vals` such that the (always single) non-missing value in `x` remains intact; that is, I'm looking for a vector `z` such that

```
> z <- c("c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a")
>   cbind(x, z)
     x   z  
[1,] NA  "c"
[2,] NA  "a"
[3,] NA  "b"
[4,] NA  "c"
[5,] NA  "a"
[6,] "b" "b"
[7,] NA  "c"
[8,] NA  "a"
```

I figure that there must be some nice way using permutations, `base`-vector-filling or the modulo-operators. I just can't seem to get it to work in a compact statement.

### Edit

I implemented a method to do what I'm looking for. However, (1) it's not as compact as I think it possible and (2) it's not working if the target vector is shorter than the possible values

```
ticket_fill <- function(x, vals) {
  
  ind_val <- which(!is.na(x))
  
  cand <- rep(vals, length(x))
  ind <- which(cand == x[ind_val])
  ind <- min(ind[ind >= ind_val])
  
  ind <- (1:length(x)) + ind
  
  cand[ind]
}
```

e.g., `x <- c(NA, "b")` gives

```
> x <- c(NA, "b")
> cbind(x, ticket_fill(x, letters[1:3]))
     x      
[1,] NA  "c"
[2,] "b" "a"
```

Comment: Does the target vector always have only one value?

Comment: yes, only one non-missing in the target vector

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
rotate<-function(x, n) {
    x[(n + seq_along(x) - 1) %% length(x) + 1]
}

fillvals<-function(x, vals) {
    suppressWarnings(x[]<-rotate(vals, match(setdiff(x, NA), vals) -
                          match(FALSE, is.na(x))))
    x
}
fillvals(x, vals)
#[1] "c" "a" "b" "c" "a" "b" "c" "a"
```

Some other tests:

```
fillvals(c(NA,"b"), vals)
#[1] "a" "b"
fillvals(c("c",NA), vals)
#[1] "c" "a"
```

**EDIT**
From the great Maël's comment, we can simplify the function using `rep`:

```
fillvals<-function(x, vals) {
        rep(rotate(vals, match(setdiff(x, NA), vals) -
                              match(FALSE, is.na(x))),
                              length.out = length(x))
}
```

Comment: works beautifully in production; pretty much the approach I tried to follow but failed miserably.

Comment: I essentially had the same answer, but using `rep(vals, length.out = length(x))` to create the repeated/recycled vector. +1

Comment: @Maël great catch! I didn't think of rep, since it's not a very common usage. Will make an edit.